# how to read an image file like jpg and display it on screen pixel by pixel?

Tags: operating-system, pixel, vga

I am doing my own OS(from scratch) **which is not based on any pre-existing kernels or OS**. So i know screen is divided into 80*25 and i know that usually it is like 0xB8000 can hold a attributes of character in 0xB8001 and **i know only that much**.

But how to display an image on screen pixel by pixel? how do i address each pixel and send the data(colour)?

Currently i am printing text on screen using 0xB8000. so if i address 0xB8000 am i adressing a pixel?
I am not at all clear in this aspect. so pls help.

please note that i am not using and i can't use any graphic libraries or so because i'm building my own OS from scratch.

**I want to do this in C even though i know assembly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

80x25 is so called "text mode", that is a byte in memory corresponds to a character on the monitor. You normally switch video adapter into "graphics mode" and you have pixel space.

You can start your reading from here: [CGA - Standard Text Modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter#Standard_text_modes).

Comment: thank you. then how do i switch from text mode to graphics mode? how do i address each pixel or each memory location?

Comment: In real mode using BIOS you could do it with an interrupt `10h`. Sorry, details faded out with time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H

Comment: thank you sir. but how can i do it without calling interrupt 10h because calling int10h for every displaying pixel may not suit very well.

Comment: Read on graphics modes, you can access all pixels at a certain memory location.

Comment: thank you sir. but someone please tell me how to read a jpg or such image file to display it? how is the data stored? will the colours be in hex?